# Dimensions of mel spectrogram

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, transformer, audio-recognition

Can someone explain me dimensions in ASR? For example, if I have an audio, convert it to mel spectrogram and now I have a tensor of dimension [1, 128, 850]. Am I understand right that 128 - number of channels and if i will apply CNN for input, input channels will be equal to 128? And what is 850? For example, if I will apply transformer for input mel spectrogram, number of embeddings that I will pass to encoder is 850? Thank you in advance

Comment: How did you create the mel spectrogram? Order of the dimensons may wary based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a mel-spectrogram there is only **1** channel (magnitude), and two spatial dimensions: **n_mels** mel bands, and **T** time-frames (depends on length of the audio).

The order of the dimensions n the mel spectrogram may vary based on exactly which implementation you have used to generate it, which you have not specified.
But as n_mels=128 is a common setting, and the `(n_mels, time_frames)` is the standard order in librosa, I assume that 850 is the number of time-frames in your example.

Note that the order used by Convolution Neural Networks may also vary. For example in [keras Conv2d](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/) the default data_format='channels_last'. Which means that your vector should be `(batch_size, n_mels, time_frames, 1)` instead of `(batch_size, 1, n_mels, time_frames)`.